# Is there any way of sharing ownership of a Google folder

Tags: google-drive, access-control

I have a folder which contains documents that a fair number of people need to be able to edit.  I'm the owner of the folder, and I have set it up so that only the owner can add people to the folder after we had a couple of instances where 'helpful' colleagues have given people editing rights without checking if they should have them.

I'm now going away on hols and have other jobs, so ideally I would like to share the ownership of the folder with a colleague so that people can be added while I'm away.  I can't give ownership to a group, and I can't find a way of setting more than one owner of a folder.

Has anyone found a way of sharing ownership with other people?  Or is that just something that can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Google Drive sharing settings only allows one owner and it should be a user account. The alternative is to create a `role account` and assign the ownership of files and folders to that account.

A `role account` is a regular account created for cases where is required to share the password with someone or something. In this case, the password could be shared with a substitute during the absences of the person in charge.

Bear in mind that the Google accounts require some "person information" like given name, surname and birthday. For the first two use something descriptive, for the last use a date very close to the birthday of person in charge otherwise the account could be blocked due to age requirements.

Comment: Makes sense.  We have a managed google environment for the entire organisation so I will talk to our service desk.  Thank you for your quick reply!